# proc sql code in SAS not filtering properly

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I hope this is not a very very obvious, but if it is please don't kill me, I'm really new at this and struggle to find much info.

This code should do the following:

-grab columns from 2 different tables
-only select rows that are not on a third table on a particular date

```
proc sql;
create table DiallerExtra as
SELECT a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER,
    b.CURRENT_FIRST_NAME,
    b.TELEPHONE_NUMBER
FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b
WHERE a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
NOT IN (SELECT AgreementNumber
FROM TABLE3 (WHERE =(DeleteDate >= today()-1)))
;
quit;
```

I first tried this (below) and it worked fine to filter the results (I ended up with 15 rows only).

```
proc sql;
create table DiallerExtra as
SELECT a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
FROM TABLE1 a
WHERE a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
NOT IN (SELECT AgreementNumber
FROM TABLE3 (WHERE =(DeleteDate >= today()-1)))
;
quit;
```

But when I tried the first code, it doesn't seem to be filtering correctly cause it spits out all the agreements on TABLE2, which is a lot.

Comment: I don't understand this syntax:  `(WHERE =(DeleteDate >= today()-1))`.  What does this do in `proc sql`?  It is not valid SQL syntax and I haven't come across it before.

Comment: And don't forget a join condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it filters for that date. My manager use it, I've used it and I've also seen it used in tutorials and such :)

Comment: @jarlh where would that go? I tried including one but wasn't able to find where to put it exactly... can you make an answer please?

Comment: Something like FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.somecolumn = t2.somecol

Comment: You don't have any condition to decide which observations in TABLE1 should be matched to the observations from TABLE2.  How are you supposed to know that which customer goes with which agreement?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff SAS SQL allows you to add dataset options, one of which is a `where` condition. It prevents you from needing to create a subquery and instead will perform the filtering while reading the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "filtering" of your NOT IN logic is not the problem.

Add something to tell SQL how to combine TABLE1 and TABLE2.

If you want to combine two tables with SQL you need to tell it how to match the observations. Otherwise every observation in TABLE1 is matched to every observation in TABLE2.  In your first example even if there is only one observation in TABLE1 with a value of A.AGREEMENT_NUMBER that is in the TABLE3 observations that match your WHERE= dataset option then it will be matched with every observation in TABLE2.  So if TABLE2 had 100 customers the result set will have 100 observations.

So add another condition to your WHERE statement. For example if both TABLE1 and TABLE2 have AGREEMENT_NUMBER then perhaps you want to match on that.

```
create table DiallerExtra as
SELECT a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
     , b.CURRENT_FIRST_NAME
     , b.TELEPHONE_NUMBER
FROM TABLE1 a
   , TABLE2 b
WHERE a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER = b.AGREEMENT_NUMBER
  and a.AGREEMENT_NUMBER NOT IN 
     (SELECT AgreementNumber FROM TABLE3 (WHERE =(DeleteDate >= today()-1)))
;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was sure it wasn't a very complicated solution but I wasn't sure where to change exactly.